# Proper way to reference images inside a vue component in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this Vue component inside **resources/js/components** in my laravel project, and I'm trying to reference a static image but I cant get it right.

I tried placing this image in my **public/imgs** path and tried the following code in my vue component but none worked:

```
<img src="imgs/sample.jpg">
<img :src="require('imgs/sample.jpg')">
```

I tried placing it at a different location - **resources/imgs** - but it didn't work as well:

```
<img src="../imgs/sample.jpg">
<img :src="require('../imgs/sample.jpg')">
```

What is the proper way of referencing this static image?

Comment: `<img src="/imgs/sample.jpg">` ?? (If they are located in your `/public/imgs/` folder)

Comment: got it. a whitespace in the actual folder name threw me off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code i have posted above is actually the right way to reference images inside vue components

```
<img src="imgs/sample.jpg">
```

What I have gotten wrong was the name of the folder which included a **whitespace**. Instead of just "imgs", the folder name was "imgs "

Answer (score 0):

If is static image reference, You can refer images directly using '@'

Example:

`<img src="@/assets/images/home.png"/>`